# Alternative to saving JWT token in local storage?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, graphql-js

What is the secure standard for saving authorization/authentication with GraphQL/Apollo Client and Server.

Currently in both the course I am taking and the Apollo docs, they are of saving a JWT token into local storage and attaching it to any header requests to the server to be validated on the server-side.

I understand that saving a token into localstorage is a severe vunerablity.

So what are the safest alternatives? Is there a way to save a JWT token into a cookie? Is saving the token into a cookie the "industry" standard?

Even in the Apollo docs they use localstorage
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/

````
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});```
````

Comment: Using localStorage is not necessarily a severe vulnerability. The difference between localStorage and sessionStorage is primarily expiry. Using localStorage can be safe, depending of the expiry time of the token. Also, sessionStorage comes with some drawbacks too that affect usability.

Comment: Ah, and sessionStorage also encapsulates "cookies" right?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean with “also encapsulates cookies”.

Comment: Sorry - I am saying do cookies fall into the category of "session storage"?

Comment: Not exactly, unlike sessionStorage cookies are shared between browser tabs/windows and persisted until expiry. SessionStorage on the other hand is cleared when you close a tab and recreated (empty) when you open a new tab. This behavior can cause usability issues for users of your app because they probably have to login each time they open a new tab.

Comment: I’m not familiar with Apollo GraphQL or their authentication system but if the token has a short enough lifetime, there should be no problem storing it in localStorage. The documentation does not mention token lifetime but if the token is a JWT you can use https://jwt.io/ to inspect the contents of the token to find out it’s expiry.

Comment: +1. I've seen pretty much everywhere that saving a JWT in broswer storage is a vulnerability, but Apollo does this right in their docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `sessionStorage`, it remove the data when session finish and the values can access only by your web, more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

or `To keep them secure, you should always store JWTs inside an httpOnly cookie.` from: https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/

Comment: HttpOnly will prevent JavaScript from being able to access the token which renders is useless for this use case.

Comment: nice observation, why you need to access the token? it will send automatically, then in server youo can access to the token